# Какую мне использовать альтернативу git или как настроить сам git для моих целей?

Tags: репозиторий

Задача такая. Я хочу организовать свои репозитории как у гугла:

```
/ - (account root)
/android - (simple directory)
/android/openjdk - (git repo)
```

```
 ~ $ git clone --depth 1 https://server.com/me/android/openjdk
```

Черт его знает, как у `git` (не конкретного сервиса aka `GitHub`, а вообще `git`) дела с такой организацией репозиториев, если она вообще возможна.

`Google` (для Android) и `LibreOffice` используют `Gerrit`. Все бы ничего, но мне при такой структуре папок мне нужна возможность делать **приватные репозитории** (поскольку впринципе я хочу использовать хостинг кода не только для публикации готовых программ и их кода, но и для **бэкапа** кода, который ещё в процессе написания (плюс, я работаю с нескольких устройств, так что тут ещё получается синхронизация. Условно, дописал часть кода из дома на пк, часть кода уже с ноутбука. Или, если что-то будет с пк или ноутбуком - на сервере будет весь код, и я смогу продолжить работу со второго устройства)).

Конечно, можно было бы вообще использовать классические `file-backup/sync` утилиты (вроде какого нибудь `Syncthing`), но там мне не будет хватать интеграции с `Git` - aka ветки репозиториев, коммиты и прочее.

> Что можете посоветовать? Какие утилиты для бэкапа или работы с кодом
> можете посоветовать?

Может, мне надо как-то настроить `git` (или вообще саму `Gitea`, если уж речь зайдет про конкретные сервисы-хостинги кода), `gerrit`, тот же `Syncthing`, или использовать какую-то совершенно иную утилиту? Писать своё... ну, мне на это сил не хватит, я вряд ли смогу такое сделать...

Comment: Положить всё дерево каталогов в DropBox? Интересно, как будут работать репозитории после синхронизации через DropBox.

Comment: Я так и не понял чем тут не подходит git и GitHub/gitlab/etc

Comment: Да мне нужно организовать репозитории определённым образом. Ну, я вообще хз, зависит ли это архитектурно от Git как такового или же от конкретного хостинга (github, gitlab, Gitea, etc).

Comment: Сделай подмодули

Comment: git submodules это немного не то. Это удобно, если есть приложение, которое собирается с сторонней библиотекой. В моём случае это бы даже не везде подошло, не говоря уже о том, что у меня задача чуть иная.

Comment: А проблема в том, что мне не очень удобно видеть стопку по разному названных репозиториев однословной шеренгой. Хочется структуры, как в Gerrit, но с возможностями обычного git. И прямо на web-page, а не только в консоли сервера. Пока что сижу на Syncthing, ибо ничего лучше не нашёл, плюс его использую для, собственно, синхронизации личных файлов. Опять же, жду ответа на свой вопрос, ибо без git может быть не очень удобно, особенно если хочешь сделать ветки или просто хочешь изменения фиксировать для возможности отката `git revert $commit` (или как там команду для отката до `aabbcc`-коммита).